# DefaultHighlightPainter keeps shifting in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextpane

I am currently working on a application that reads a big text, and highlights a specific substring inside that text. And it kinda works...

But it seems that (and I have no clue why) the highligt keeps shifting every time it highlights the string.

```
public List<int[]> findString(String text) {        
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    List<int[]> highlightPositions = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    JTextPane pane = getTextPane();

    String paneText = pane.getText().toLowerCase();

    int end = 0;
    while (paneText.indexOf(text, end) != -1) {         

        int start = paneText.indexOf(text, end);
        end = start + text.length();        

        highlightPositions.add(new int[] {start, end});                 
    }

    try {
        highlight(highlightPositions);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }       
return null;
}
```

and this is the code that does the actual highlighting

```
public void highlight(List<int[]> highlightPositions) throws BadLocationException {
    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);

    JTextPane textPane = getTextPane();     

    for (int[] position : highlightPositions) {
        System.out.println("Highlight: " + position[0] + " : " + position[1]);
        textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(position[0], position[1], highlightPainter);

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT:
Here is how it looks when I attempt to highlight the word "Device".

[Highlighting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dl6P.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by *"the highligt keeps shifting"*? Also, when I try to reproduce this, it works for me - Please consider providing a runnable [mcve].

Comment: I just updated my post with a picture. That is how it looks when I attempt to highlight the word "Device".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String paneText = pane.getText().toLowerCase();
```

Don't use `getText()`. The `getText()` method will return the string with the end-of-line string for the platform which in the case of Windows is `\r\n`.  However the Document only stores `\n` for the EOL string so you have a mismatch of offsets for every extra line in the Document.

The solution is to use:

```
String paneText = pane.getDocument().getText().toLowerCase();
```

See [Text and New Lines](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more complete information on the problem.